# How can I remove a directory with rm - rf?

Tags: linux, rm

I try to remove a folder with

```
rm -rf foldername
```

… but it says

> rm: cannot remove folder :is a directory.

What's wrong?

Comment: I know it goes without saying but given the question; be very careful with rm, particularly with -r being used. its one of the commands you really want to make sure you know what it'll do. Try using -i which will prompt for each deletion, until you get comfortable with it.

Comment: Does the folder you are trying to delete contain any special characters or spaces?  Have you tried putting foldername in quotes?

Comment: The issue is difficult to explain without knowing further details. Are there really no other error messages? Could be that one or more files could not be removed because of permission problems. In this case the parent directory cannot be removed also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the space between `-` and `rf`.

Comment: sorry, i mistyped. there is no space between - and rf actually.

Comment: what does ls -l foldername and whoami give ?

Comment: sorry, an admin has told me that there is a script that removes -rf whenever I use it. problem is solved.

Comment: LOL! Worthy to be remembered in the all time favourites UNIX issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the foldername you're trying to remove literally `.` Because it is defined as an error to attempt to remove `.` and `..`. Instead, change one level up and then remove it.

Comment: You have my upvote, but the error I get when I try removing current directory is different. `rm -rf .` results in `: rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'`; when I remove it by the full path, I can successfully do it.